# How to plot a graph based on user selection in MatLab

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-guide

How can I create a graph which has points generated depending on what the user selects on the GUI I am creating in MatLab. Please take a look at the image of the GUI. So depending on what radio button they select in the 2 radio button groups, i want a point put on a graph which then i can generate.
[image]

Comment: This is too broad of a question. You're going to want to look into defining [callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html)

Comment: @Suever I don't know if this clears things up but basically I want a graph created based on the what the user selects.

Comment: I understand that, I didn't say that it wasn't clear what you wanted. I said that it's too broad (i.e. you need to try to do it yourself first using the link I posted and come to us with specific questions)

Comment: @Suever okay I created a submit button and assigned it a callback function, but I am still not sure how to get it plot a graph based on user selection of the radio buttons.

Comment: You can set the Callback for the radio buttons so that when you select one you can see which one was selected and then call `plot` commands as you need.